# Can VmWare Update Manager Logs be Deleted?

Tags: vmware-vsphere

I was recently reviewing a Windows 2008 R2 server that has low disk space.

I didn't know if VMware Update Manager logs located in: `C:\ProgramData\VMware Update Manager\Logs` can be deleted or at least the oldest ones deleted. They are taking up about 15GB of space on the drive. I didn't know what these are used for or if they can be deleted. The furthest back they stretch is 4/25/2015 of this year and several logs from 2 - 3 years ago. Many of the files are `.dmp` files and several `.txt` documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they can.

Presumably you have backups of the server so they can always be recovered from there if needed.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I made a backup of the logs to a different drive and deleted them off C: